# Div responsive with padding and vertical scrollbar

Tags: responsive

I have this code, when window width shrinks, div is responsive, but on height side is fixed. Is there a way to get vertical scrollbar when window height goes small (when 'b' is higher than 'a') so I can scroll up and down?

```
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    <div class="c"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L2fmghmm/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try it with:

```
@media (max-height: 600px) {
  .b {
    overflow: auto;
  }
}
```

If I didn't understand your issue, please correct me.

https://jsfiddle.net/RezaScript/0kxef3a8/

Comment: Doesnt work quite right if you expand 'a' tall enough.

Comment: @Toniq do you mean the window with of `.a`? You could also replace `overflow: auto` with `overflow: scroll`.

Comment: Just resize window height long enough and you will see the problem.